# Where can we modify the default links of the footer in Magento?

Tags: magento, footer, magento-1.6

I want to get rid of the links in the footer of my website, someone started the dev of that website and left, now I can't modify it, because when I'm in the footer.phtml i can see that code :

```
<!-- Footer -->
<div id="footer">
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo $this->getCopyright(); ?></li>
    </ul>
    <?php echo Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode('footer_navigation')->getValue('html'); ?>
    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<!-- /Footer -->
```

I can't find the place where that class is looking for the links `Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode('footer_navigation')->getValue('html')`

I've been looking in catalog.xml where I found `<reference name="footer_links">` but if I delet the code inside, nothing happen, it doesn't seem to be linked in any way with that.

I got the same problem in my menu where  I see that class I don't understand : `$categories = $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtmlCustom2(0, 'level-top');` Where does that refer too ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login to your admin panel and go to System->Custom Variables. You should find the footer links there. You can remove the links through here (by deleting the HTML and plain-text fields), or by taking out the piece of code that loads the footer links variable (the line that calls `loadByCode('footer_navigation')`).

You can also delete the variable through the admin panel, but if you do this, you should also remove the code that calls it; it won't crash, but it can lead to confusion down the road.